# inputText value is getting wiped out

Tags: visualforce, javascript

What is the best way to have a better user experience without delay as communicating to the server as shown in the GIF image when the user enter the value in the inputText box and then checked the checkbox it wipes out the inputText value

Here is my code:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="aSelectItem" action="{!doSelectItem}" rerender="pb">
  <apex:param name="contextItem" value="" assignTo="{!contextItem}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>

  <apex:actionFunction name="aDeselectItem" action="{!doDeselectItem}" rerender="pb">
  <apex:param name="contextItem" value="" assignTo="{!contextItem}"/>
 </apex:actionFunction> 

<apex:actionFunction name="updateQuantity" action="{!updateQuantity}" rerender="pb">
   <apex:param name="contextItem" value="" assignTo="{!contextItem}"/>
   <apex:param name="contextItemValue" value="" assignTo="{!contextItemValue}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>


<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!AccountWraps}" var="a" id="pbt">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!selectedAllProperties}" onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this)" />
                    </apex:facet> 
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.checked}" styleClass="cbStyleClass" onclick="doCheckboxChange(this,'{!a.act.Id}')" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Agent Commission Percentage">
                    <apex:inputText value="{!a.quantity}" onchange="updateTextChange(this, '{!a.act.Id}')"/>
                </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //function to handle checkbox selection
    function doCheckboxChange(cb,itemId)
    {
        if(cb.checked==true){
            aSelectItem(itemId);
        }
        else{
            aDeselectItem(itemId);
        }        
    }    

    function updateTextChange(obj, itemId){

        updateQuantity(itemId, $(obj).val());
    }
    </script>
```

Controller:

```
  public String contextItem {get;set;}
  public Set<Id> selectedIds {get;set;}
  public Map<Id, Decimal> quantityMap {get;set;}
  public void doSelectItem()
    { 
        this.selectedIds.add(this.contextItem);
    }

  public void updateQuantity()
  {
    this.quantityMap.put(this.contextItem, 
    Decimal.valueOf(this.contextItemValue));
  }
```

[image]

Comment: can you post your implementation of the controller method `doSelectItem` ?

Comment: updated with controller code and its not much going on in the controller its simple adding/removing the ids from the list.

Comment: @NickKahn - i believe my answer is still valid. depending on how `quantityMap` is populated. The call on the checkbox may be overwriting with a 0 value vs the current value input in the checkbox.

Comment: This has something to do with `doSelectItem` controller method. Can you please post the controller code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think is going on:

1. You enter a value in the inputText which calls a method in the controller and uses the value entered
2. When you check the box you call a method in the controller but do not pass in the current value of the input text. Thus the controller is left in a race and uses the initial value (previous value).

A lot depends on what is happening in the controller BUT

if you add a param in the `doSelectItem` actionFunction

```
<apex:param name="contextItemValue" value="" assignTo="{!contextItemValue}"/>
```

and pass in the current value of the input and use that in the controller method it may help solve your immediate issue.

Ultimately though, i would look into changing your design and possibly use remote actions. calling a single function. Since they are queued changes in rapid succession will only use the latest values.

To illustrate:

Reproducible example that WORKS as expected:

**Class**

```
public class dummyClass{
    public String contextItem {get;set;}
    public String contextItemValue {get;set;}
    public boolean cbValue {get;set;}
    public String theValue {get {if(theValue == null) theValue = '0'; return theValue;}set;}

    public void doSelectItem()
    { 
        system.debug('Do Select Value: ' + contextItemValue);
        theValue = contextItemValue;
        cbValue = !cbValue;
    }

    public void updateQuantity()
    {
        system.debug('Update Quantity Value: ' + contextItemValue);
        theValue = contextItemValue;

    }

}
```

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page controller="dummyClass">
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function doCheckboxChange()
    {
        console.log($('[id$=theValue]').val());
        aSelectItem($('[id$=theValue]').val());
    }    

    function updateTextChange(obj){
        console.log($('[id$=theValue]').val());
        updateQuantity($('[id$=theValue]').val());
    }
    </script>

    <apex:form>
        <apex:actionFunction name="aSelectItem" action="{!doSelectItem}" rerender="pb">
            <apex:param name="contextItemValue" value="" assignTo="{!contextItemValue}"/>
        </apex:actionFunction>

        <apex:actionFunction name="updateQuantity" action="{!updateQuantity}" rerender="pb">
           <apex:param name="contextItemValue" value="" assignTo="{!contextItemValue}"/>
        </apex:actionFunction>

        <apex:outPutPanel layout="block" id="pb">
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!cbValue}" styleClass="cbStyleClass" onclick="doCheckboxChange(this)" />
            <apex:inputText id="theValue" value="{!theValue}" onchange="updateTextChange(this)"/>
        </apex:outPutPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The above works.

However if I change this line in the **class**

```
theValue = contextItemValue;
```

to

```
theValue = '0';
```

Or this line in the **page**

```
    //aSelectItem($('[id$=theValue]').val());
```

to

```
    aSelectItem('0');
```

It reproduces the behavior you are seeing.

Basically, whatever happens in your code as a results of:

```
this.selectedIds.add(this.contextItem);
```

and the rerender is causing a downstream change in your code that is zeroing out the value.

Comment: I did add the `<apex:param... ` to the `doSelectItem` actionFunction but that did not fix anything.

Comment: @NickKahn - did you update your controller to use it. only adding it will not help.

Comment: i'm bit lost here so what exactly should i update in the controller? `contextItemvalue` ?

Comment: @NickKahn - See updated answer. I cannot tell you specifically where to change as it is downstream in your code. Play with my examples so you can understand what is going on then debug your code and follow the log